# InstallUtil throws TypeLoadException of AssemblySignatureKeyAttribute

Tags: .net, windows-services, installutil

On the development computer there was no error when I used InstallUtil, the service was installed successfully.
I intended to install it on a different computer (it has .Net 4.0 installed), so I copied the following files to the target directory:

- InstallUtil.exe
- InstallUtil.exe.config
- InstallUtilLib.dll

After running the util in admin mode, I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Reflection.AssemblySignatureKeyAttribute' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
>   Int Ptr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInst Count, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
>   Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[] met hodInstantiationContext)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
>   Type[] ge nericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttrib
>   uteRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly&
>   lastAptcaOkAssembly, Runtime Module decoratedModule, MetadataToken
>   decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilte rType, Boolean
>   mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes,
>   RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean&
>   ctorHasParameters , Boolean& isVarArg)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decora tedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFi lterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecorate dTargetSecurityTransparent)
>   at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   asse mbly, RuntimeType caType)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit)    at
>   System.Configuration.InstallUtil.Main(String[] args)

It seems that even the InstallUtil can't be started so it can't get to install the service.
What should I check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try to run "installutil.exe" from the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ or some other relevant folder (inside C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET) ??

I mostly think, the error you see is mostly because of mismatch of .NET versions.

Comment: You are right, I was using a different version and didn't make use of the already installed one. Great catch. As a sidenote: I managed to use sc.exe instead if this.

Comment: Hey.. thanks.. sc.exe would work. But, not the best command to use, if you want to do it the right way. Please refer question below for a good justification from Hans. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692250/installing-windows-service-with-sc-exe-or-installutil-exe-there-is-difference